# MySQL Database SQL with Excel Data Has No Results

Tags: mysql, excel

I have data from MySQL database that I export into Excel.

However, when I try to query for the data using the Excel field into MySQL using SQL, no record appears.  I checked the spacing but that was not it.

Following is an example:

Here is what MySQL database displays it:  BIS    Unplugged

Here is how Excel displays it:  BIS    Unplugged

I created the following SQL:

select distinct alarm_text

from alarm_events

where alarm_text="BIS    Unplugged"

When I put the BIS Unplugged from MySQL database, the result appears as BIS    Unplugged.

When I put the BIS Unplugged from Excel, I get no result.

I tried to copy the Excel data "BIS    Unplugged" into a notepad and then put it into SQL but no result was returned.

This happens with a lot of my other data as well.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out SELECT INTO OUTFILE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). This will allow you to export a CSV which excel can then import.

```
SELECT field1
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM ts
```

Comment: I exported the SQL results into a csv file which worked.  The format is maintained in the csv file.

Comment: I am still having the same problem with the csv file.